# Using Powershell to Report AWS Security Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, security

I am new to powershell and the AWS CLI and have look and looked for someone else who has posted this...

What I'm trying to do is get the code right to create a report of each AWS Security Group that shows the inbound rules.

Something like this I would image the output would be.

`SecurityGroupName  GroupID,    Type,   Protcol,    PortRange,  Source,     Description
SSH & HTTP          gs-1111     SSH     TCP          22        0.0.0.0/0    Inbound SSH & HTTP
SSH & HTTP          gs-1111     HTTP    TCP          80        1.2.34       Inbound SSH & HTTP
HTTPS               gs-2222     HTTPS   TCP          443       0.0.0.0/0` 
'

But I can't figure it out.

I can use `$GroupID=Get-EC2SecurityGroup -Region us-east-1  |Select-Object -ExpandProperty GroupID`

```
ForEach ($item in $GroupID) {
(Get-EC2SecurityGroup -Region us-east-1 -GroupId $item).IpPermissions | Select-Object IPProtocol,IpRange, FromPort,ToPort}
```

to get the basic rule but can't seem to combine all the properties you need.  This is where my lack of powershell really hurts.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Amit, Yes, THANK You for the response.  I'm still learning a lot and am trying to understand your response better. (understanding hash tables, etc)

Comment: You can always ask and I would happily help you out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a new [Powershell array](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-5.1) that will hold all the objects.
Later, run over all the security groups in the specific region and add relevant data to the [hash-table object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6).
Then, just add the object to the array we created earlier.

**Code snippet:**

```
$region = 'YOUR_REGION'
$allSG = @()

Get-EC2SecurityGroup  -Region $region  | % {

    $obj = @{

    Description = $_.IpPermission.Ipv4Ranges.Description
    GroupId = $_.GroupId
    SecurityGroupName   = $_.GroupName
    Source = $_.IpPermission.Ipv4Ranges.CidrIp
    FromPort = $_.IpPermission.FromPort
    ToPort = $_.IpPermission.ToPort
    Protocol = $_.IpPermission.IpProtocol
    }

    $object = new-object psobject -Property $obj
    $allSG += $object 

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Insights:**

1. Some Descriptions might be missing.
2. The From/To Port represent the Type (e.g - 80 = HTTP, 443 = HTTPS)

More about [Get-EC2SecurityGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2SecurityGroup.html).